# Can I make JBoss deploy without all the Java EE stuff and act like tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss

I like tomcat but not Tomcat IDE tools.
I Love jboss's IDE tools.
But when i deploy my app in jboss i get all sorts of EE errors because it's usual ran in tomcat without all that EE related stuff.

And I don't want to migrate to JBoss 7. My app is a beast that would be a mammoth effort.

can i make jboss7 or wildfly act like tomcat? Is there some server configuration that can do that?

Or maybe undertow is the answer?

any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps if you show us the errors we can determine whether migration is really mammoth or not.

Comment: I have migrated about 50 different business apps from appserverA to Jboss5eap,6eap,7community,etc.  and this one will be a bear. trying to avoid that at all costs.